# Groupby two columns and print different quantiles as seperate columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Type A', 'Event1', 1, 2, 3], ['Type A', 'Event1', 4, 5, 6], ['Type A', 'Event1', 7, 8, 9],
['Type A', 'Event2', 10, 11, 12], ['Type A', 'Event2', 13, 14, 15], ['Type A', 'Event2', 16, 17, 18], \
['Type B', 'Event1', 19, 20, 21], ['Type B', 'Event1', 22, 23, 24], ['Type B', 'Event1', 25, 26, 27], \
['Type B', 'Event2', 28, 29, 30], ['Type B', 'Event2', 31, 32, 33], ['Type B', 'Event2', 34, 35, 36]])

df.columns = ['TypeName', 'EventNumber', 'PricePart1', 'PricePart2', 'PricePart3']

print(df)
```

Gives:

```
   TypeName EventNumber  PricePart1  PricePart2  PricePart3
0    Type A      Event1           1           2           3
1    Type A      Event1           4           5           6
2    Type A      Event1           7           8           9
3    Type A      Event2          10          11          12
4    Type A      Event2          13          14          15
5    Type A      Event2          16          17          18
6    Type B      Event1          19          20          21
7    Type B      Event1          22          23          24
8    Type B      Event1          25          26          27
9    Type B      Event2          28          29          30
10   Type B      Event2          31          32          33
11   Type B      Event2          34          35          36
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
df['Average'] = df[['PricePart1', 'PricePart2', 'PricePart3']].mean(axis = 1)

print(df)

       TypeName EventNumber  PricePart1  PricePart2  PricePart3  Average
0    Type A      Event1           1           2           3      2.0
1    Type A      Event1           4           5           6      5.0
2    Type A      Event1           7           8           9      8.0
3    Type A      Event2          10          11          12     11.0
4    Type A      Event2          13          14          15     14.0
5    Type A      Event2          16          17          18     17.0
6    Type B      Event1          19          20          21     20.0
7    Type B      Event1          22          23          24     23.0
8    Type B      Event1          25          26          27     26.0
9    Type B      Event2          28          29          30     29.0
10   Type B      Event2          31          32          33     32.0
11   Type B      Event2          34          35          36     35.0
```

Now that I have this new column called `Average`, I can group by `TypeName`, `EventNumber` columns and find the 25th and 50th percentile using this peice of code:

```
print(df.groupby(['TypeName', 'EventNumber'])['Average'].quantile([0.25, 0.50]).reset_index())
```

What I have:

```
  TypeName EventNumber  level_2  Average
0   Type A      Event1     0.25      3.5
1   Type A      Event1     0.50      5.0
2   Type A      Event2     0.25     12.5
3   Type A      Event2     0.50     14.0
4   Type B      Event1     0.25     21.5
5   Type B      Event1     0.50     23.0
6   Type B      Event2     0.25     30.5
7   Type B      Event2     0.50     32.0
```

I want the `level_2` as seperate columns with the values from `Average` column like with the output DataFrame I've created:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Type A', 'Event1', 3.5, 5], ['Type A', 'Event2', 12.5, 14], ['Type B', 'Event1', 21.5, 23], ['Type B', 'Event2', 30.5, 32]])
df1.columns = ['TypeName', 'EventNumber', '0.25', '0.50']
print(df1)
```

What I want:

```
  TypeName EventNumber  0.25  0.50
0   Type A      Event1   3.5     5
1   Type A      Event2  12.5    14
2   Type B      Event1  21.5    23
3   Type B      Event2  30.5    32
```

I'm super sure that this is some duplicate, but I have searched through StackOverflow and not found my answer because of the difficulty wording the question (or maybe just that I'm stupid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['TypeName', 'EventNumber'])['Average']
       .quantile([0.25, 0.50])
       .unstack()
       .reset_index())
print (df)

  TypeName EventNumber  0.25   0.5
0   Type A      Event1   3.5   5.0
1   Type A      Event2  12.5  14.0
2   Type B      Event1  21.5  23.0
3   Type B      Event2  30.5  32.0
```

**Syntactic sugar solution** - new column `Average` is not necessary, is possible use `groupby` with `3 Series`:

```
s = df[['PricePart1', 'PricePart2', 'PricePart3']].mean(axis = 1)

df = (s.groupby([df['TypeName'], df['EventNumber']])
       .quantile([0.25, 0.50])
       .unstack()
       .reset_index())
print (df)

  TypeName EventNumber  0.25   0.5
0   Type A      Event1   3.5   5.0
1   Type A      Event2  12.5  14.0
2   Type B      Event1  21.5  23.0
3   Type B      Event2  30.5  32.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: I'm guessing my question may probably be taken down

Comment: @Abhishek - Why do you think so?

Comment: Although I haven't read other answer related to `groupby, print multiple columns` completely, I have seen many variations of my question asking to do something similar, and if the response to my question is more straightforward than those other questions that I saw, chances are many have run into my issue and worded it better and gotten a reply.

Comment: You are a god. I hope I work hard enough to come to your level.

Comment: @Abhishek - I think sometimes get nice idea, sometimes not. It depends. So no god ;)

Comment: hi @jezreal, can you tell me what is the difference between `df.xs` and `df.loc`

Comment: yes, he is a master, helping me all the time :D @Abhishek

Comment: @pyd - sure, `xs` is used only with `Multiindex` DataFrame and `loc` is more general, selcing by label. In `MultiIndex` DataFrame is `loc` used with [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

Comment: yes, I tried `loc` in `multi index` like `df.loc['BB','MyData']` 'BB' is level 0 index and `MyData` is column gives `keyerror`

Comment: @pyd - use tuple like `df.loc[('BB','MyData'), :]`

Comment: no not working, 'MyData' is a column name, not in index

Comment: Can you create data sample?

Comment: go to [pandas cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html) and search for `Slicing a multi-index with xs`

Comment: @pyd - Use `print(df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['BB',:],'MyData'])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176139/discussion-between-pyd-and-jezrael).